# Guard of the docstrip

Tags: docstrip

In docstrip, there is something called guard. For example, `%<*install>` and `%</install>` are used for producing the `.ins` installation file. `%<*driver>` and `%</driver>` are used for the documentation.

- What is the function of the `internal` guard (see the [post](https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/) of Joseph Wright for example)?
- How many predefined guards there are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no predefined guards, the use of `install` and `driver` in this manner is at best conventional. In the batch file options get passed to `\from` which decide which guards are active when building the current file.

Therefore it's not possible to say in general what `internal` is used for without seeing the actual package / batch file.

Sometimes there is a guard which which is not referenced by any `\from` in the batch file, often named `gobble` or `internal`. Since it is never referenced it is always inactive and the code guarded by it is never written into any output file. These are useful to add some commands to the `.dtx` file without having it appear anywhere else.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141567/discussion-on-answer-by-marcel-kruger-guard-of-the-docstrip).